# How to write EXIF data to an image in C#?

Tags: c#, exif

I have great trouble to write EXIF data to an image. So far I have managed to write data that requires a string as input. However I am at loss on how to do it for elements that require a different type (e.g. exposure time, shutter speed).

I am following [this](http://www.thevalvepage.com/swmonkey/2013/12/23/exif-tags-in-c/) guide but there is no example for something besides a string. This [website](https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html) explains which data type I have to use and the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-read-image-metadata) provides the corresponding numerical value. Unfortunately I am unable to use this to solve my problem.
To find out which ID is corresponding to which value, I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id?view=netframework-4.8) list and the offical [documentation](https://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF#page=60).

```
System.Drawing.Image imgEXIF = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D:/def.jpg");
System.Drawing.Image imgDummy = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D:/IMG_3214.jpg");
System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem item = imgDummy.PropertyItems[0];
item.Id = 0x9286;
item.Type = 2; //String
item.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World\r\nthis is a test\0");
item.Len = item.Value.Length;
imgEXIF.SetPropertyItem(item);
imgEXIF.Save("D:/ghi.jpg");
```

Any help on how to write EXIF data that is not a string would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What goes into `Value` on the `PropertyItem` is a byte array based on the corresponding `Type` for that field. For the text fields you can already do, that byte array takes the form of an `ASCII` byte array which is null terminated. The other types I have commented below under `TagTypes`. For the Exposure Time field, this is an 8 byte array consisting of two unsigned 32-bit integers - the numerator, followed by the denominator. We can use the `BitConverter.GetBytes()` method to convert `uint` (unsigned 32-bit integer) to a 4 byte representation - then simply join with another byte array to get the pair of numerator and denominator.

Here are some extensions which show how to use a Short / type 3 field and a Rational / type 5 field in addition to a Type 2 string field:

```
public static class ImageMetaExtensions
{
    public static void SetMaxAperture(this Image image, uint numerator, uint denominator)
    {
        SetMetaDataItem(image, MAX_APERTURE, (short)TagTypes.RATIONAL, GetPairUnsigned32Integer(numerator, denominator));
    }

    public static void SetExposureTime(this Image image, uint numerator, uint denominator)
    {
        SetMetaDataItem(image, EXPOSURE_TIME, (short)TagTypes.RATIONAL, GetPairUnsigned32Integer(numerator, denominator));
    }

    public static void SetUserComment(this Image image, string text)
    {
        SetMetaDataItem(image, USER_COMMENT, (short)TagTypes.ASCII, GetNullTerminatedString(text));
    }

    public static void Set35mmFocalLength(this Image image, short focalLength)
    {
        SetMetaDataItem(image, FOCALLENGTH_35MM, (short)TagTypes.SHORT, BitConverter.GetBytes(focalLength));
    }

    public enum TagTypes : short
    {
        BYTE = 1, // 8 bit unsigned integer
        ASCII = 2,
        SHORT = 3, // 16-bit unsigned integer
        LONG = 4, // 32-bit unsigned integer
        RATIONAL = 5, // two unsigned longs - first numerator, second denominator
        UNDEFINED = 6, // any value depending on field definition
        SLONG = 7, // signed 32-bit
        SRATIONAL = 10 // signed pair of 32-bit numerator/denominator
    }

    private static void SetMetaDataItem(Image image, int id, short type, byte[] data)
    {
        PropertyItem anyItem = image.PropertyItems[0];
        anyItem.Id = id;
        anyItem.Len = data.Length;
        anyItem.Type = type;
        anyItem.Value = data;
        image.SetPropertyItem(anyItem);
    }

    private static byte[] GetPairUnsigned32Integer(uint numerator, uint denominator)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(numerator).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(denominator)).ToArray();
    }

    private static byte[] GetNullTerminatedString(string text)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text + "\0");
    }

    private const int EXPOSURE_TIME = 0x829A;      
    private const int USER_COMMENT = 0x9286;
    private const int MAX_APERTURE = 0x9205;
    private const int FOCALLENGTH_35MM = 0xA405;
}
```

Usage:

```
System.Drawing.Image myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\someimage.jpg");
myImage.SetExposureTime(1, 30); // 1/30sec
myImage.SetUserComment("Hello, world");
myImage.Set35mmFocalLength(5);
myImage.Save(@"c:\temp\someotherimage.jpg"); // save somewhere else
```